# gcloud crashed (TokenRevokeError): invalid_request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm currently experiencing inconsistency when trying to revoke my gcloud credentials after I'm done using my service account.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=mykey.json
{commands...}
gcloud auth revoke
```

At times the `revoke` command does work, but sometimes it (randomly?) fails with this error:

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (TokenRevokeError): invalid_request
>
> If you would like to report this issue, please run the following
>   command:   gcloud feedback
>
> To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
>   gcloud info --run-diagnostics

When this happens, I can see that running `gcloud auth list` afterwards still lists the account, though it isn't marked as active.
While after a successful `revoke`, the account is not listed at all (makes sense, as it has been revoked and removed).

Did anybody experience this issue?

Comment: I would make sure that the latest version is installed. `gcloud components update` otherwise you need to contact Google as per the crash instructions.

Comment: I've upgraded to the latest version (`238.0.0`) and unfortunately the issue persists. I've sent a feedback to Google.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to the latest version of gcloud per @john-hanley's suggestion.

Please see the documentation for [`gcloud auth revoke`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/revoke).

It is **not** possible to revoke service account tokens.

The message you're receiving is unhelpful (although accurate, it is an invalid request) but you should **not** see the credentials listed after issuing the command and this may be addressed by upgrading.

Comment: Thanks. Upgrading unfortunately did not help. I've gone through gcloud's documentation various time before and couldn't find any helpful information either. Retrying to revoke gives the odd message of `No credentials available to revoke` even though `gcloud revoke list` still lists the account. I'll try checking with the team at Google.